# How to using formula field for contact custom field allow only two digit numbers?

Tags: formula-field, custom-field, contact

I created one formula field in contact object. When I give text with numbers(Before text and numbers(Ex: tsdhsgj12) or after text and numbers(Ex: 12gsdjgsjgfs)) in the input contact custom filed, it will save or allow only two digit numbers. Not displaying error message or validation messages. Could you please anybody help on this.

Currently using `IF(ISBLANK(Test__c), 0, 1)` in the formula field.

Comment: @Folkert, Please give any related example as per above requirement

Comment: What is the use case? What is the field type of Test__c? If you want to get any help, you need to provide more information.

Comment: @ Folkert, Test__c field type is Text. When I give the Text with numbers in the field it will choose only numbers. Do not take text with out error message.

Comment: Do you mean you want a validation rule? That's something else than a formula field, although it uses the same concepts.

Comment: @Folkert, If possible in the validation rule please give me suggestion. Other wise using formula field  please give me suggestion.

Comment: So do you want to prevent saving of the record if it does not contain numbers? Or do you want to have a formula field that shows only the numbers that is entered in the text field? Or something else?

Comment: @Folkert,  I want to prevent saving of the record, it does contain numbers and text also. But when click the save button then we need only number will be saved.

Comment: @Folkert, sorry above scenario wrong. I want to have a formula field that shows only the numbers that is entered in the text field, we give the numbers and text in that field. But when click the save button then we need only number will be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your use case correctly, you want to prevent saving of the record if the field contains text instead of just numbers. This can be achieved by using a [validation rule.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_validation_rules.htm&type=0)

Make a validation with the following formula:

```
NOT(ISNUMBER(Test__c))
```

This will be true if the field contains more than just numbers and will thus fire the validation and prevent saving of the record.

Comment: It is working fine as well as I send previous code. But I don't want showing error messages.  When enter the text and numbers(Ex: tester32test), In this example '32' will be saved don't save the text.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible with formulas. You might need to resort to Apex to solve this.